# Android: DSA signatures - sign and verify

Tags: android, base64, digital-signature, dsa

I am having problems verifying a signature which I've just created. After signing I first convert the signature to text using Base64 and as a test I wanted to verify that I can decode the Base64 and verify the signature. This fails. Here is some code without the error handling.

I have my keypair:

```
DSAPrivateKey privateKey = (DSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
DSAPublicKey publicKey = (DSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
```

Now I sign some text and print to log output - it seems fine:

```
String text = "test";
Signature signer = null;
signer = Signature.getInstance(privateKey.getAlgorithm());
SignedObject signedObject = null;
signedObject = new SignedObject(text, privateKey, signer);
String print_signature = Base64.encodeToString(signedObject.getSignature(), Base64.DEFAULT);
System.out.println("Base64 Signature: " + print_signature);
```

Now I verify the signature using the SignedObject object created above and not the Base64. This is successful:

```
Signature verifier = null;
verifier = Signature.getInstance(publicKey.getAlgorithm());
boolean b = signedObject.verify(publicKey, verifier));
```

For my app I will only have the public certificate of the signer and the Base64 encoded string so I must verify the signature using these parameters only and can therefore AFAIK not use a SignedObject object. I used the Signature object:

```
Signature verifier1 = null;
verifier1 = Signature.getInstance(publicKey.getAlgorithm());
verifier1.initVerify(publicKey);
verifier1.update(text.getBytes()); // sorry I forgot this in original posting
byte[] sig1 = Base64.decode(print_signature, Base64.DEFAULT);
b = verifier1.verify(sig1));
```

This verification always fails (b = false).

Comment: I've added a test to verify the signature (byte array) returned by signedObject.getSignature(), which is before the Base64 encoder, with the signature sig1 (byte array), which is after the Base64 decode, and they do match. It seems that the Base64 is working fine, so the problem must be with my verifier1 object (IMHO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the `SignedObject` in the first place? What does it buy you? As for the verify failure, make sure that you get the same bytes after transmission/receiving. Are you sending/receiving in the same encoding? Is someone modifying the string?

Comment: Well I used the SignedObject object to sign the data. This signature with the data is suppose to be transmitted to another PC, but I've decided to first verify the signature before transmission. So I verify it using the SignedObject as well as the Base64 format in which I will ultimately transmit it.
So for your questions: I have not transmitted anything yet. Still testing within the function which will transmit. The encoding has been verified to be UTF-8. Nobody modified the string since it is still in same function.

Comment: Your question about why I use SignedObject, made me think. I have it because of legacy code. I removed it and changed it to use the Signature class and now the verification works!!! Still do not understand why, but at least I can continue - thx